# Inspect request object for path or url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement subdomains in my App. I have a wide sweeping restriction that says that every request has to have a subdomain. However what I really want to say is, every request that is not to the root path will need a subdomain.

The problem is that I am doing this action in my controller and I don't know how to access the request object to check and see if it is going to the root action.
Is there a way to say:

```
if request.some_method != root_path
Account.find_by_subdomain request.subdomain
end
```

Any leads would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You try using pry (binding.pry) to get a prompt inside the controller?

Comment: Im using better errors, and it gives me the ability to see into the request or the supposed request each time  i get an error. But I have actually done pry as well. Its the same output each time.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object, you should be able to call request.domain(3) to get the subdomain.

Comment: Can you add that to the question? It's not very readable here. Thanks.